# How to remove border from :visited image in nav?

Tags: html, css

Am having trouble removing the dotted border from my nav images when it is visited. I thought one of the below styles should do it, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any thoughts?

HTML

```
<li class="navprint">
<a href="printcategory.html"><img src="Images/navprint.png" alt="print button"   title="print button">
 </a>
</li>
```

CSS

```
.navprint {
width: 130px;
height: 30px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.navprint:visited {
border: none;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-image: none;
outline: none;
}

.navprint:hover {
background-color: rgb(209, 244, 239);
}

.navprint:active,  {
background-color: rgb(209, 244, 239);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a border being applied to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about what I think you're talking about, this has to do with the outline of a link that has `:focus`. So you could do something like this:

```
a:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

However, note that the outline is there for a reason -- some people navigate using the keyboard or other devices, not a mouse. The `focus` outline tells them which link currently has focus. It's generally a bad idea to remove this, unless you replace it with another indicator. So you could do:

```
a:hover, a:focus {
  background-color: rgb(209, 244, 239);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```